# How to pass class of generic type as a parameter?

Tags: java, android, generics, robospice

I have roughly the following code: (SpiceRequest is class from RoboSpice project)

```
public class MyRequest extends SpiceRequest<SparseArray<MyService>> {
    // ...
    public MyRequest() {
        // This will not work
        super(SparseArray<MyService>.class);
    }

    public SparseArray<MyService> loadDataFromNetwork() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Is it possible to pass to other method Class object of generic type?
(Sorry if it's trivial, I'm new to Java world)

*EDIT More detailed explanation*

I'm trying to replace `AsyncTask` witch loads data from network and returns `SparseArray<MyService>` with `SpiceRequest` from RoboSpice project. Witch requires providing `T` in it's constructor call.

- `MyService` is not an Android "Service"

*EDIT 2*
Problem solved by small work-around, addition of new intermediate class:

```
public class Result extends SparseArray<MyService> {}
```

And passing: `Result.class` to super `SpiceRequest` constructor

Comment: Without a definition of `OtherClass` your questsion is meaningless. And this code doesn't compile. -1

Comment: @EJP I'm explicitly said that this code is broken, and won't work on very beginning... If it would work then I would not ask this question. Anyway, I've added proper example

Comment: I agree. It was broken. And therefore meaningless.

Comment: Did you simply try to pass `SparseArray.class`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible for code in a generic class to know the class of its type parameter at run time.  The type parameter is not visible in the byte code.  This is called run time type erasure.

It's covered in great detail in the Java tutorial, starting at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html

Comment: That's actually not true. You can get the type parameter using reflection.

Comment: Ah sorry. I read `super` and I was confused. Edit your answer because I can't remove the downvote anymore.

Answer (score 0):

NO. If you want to know  type in super() or in any method, you can use getClass().